# Facebook story without external page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to use Facebook stories and custom actions without creating an external page with their ogp markup?

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK do you use?

With iOS SDK you can make the object like the below.

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"[YourAppName]:[YourObjectName]"
                                                                                             title:title
                                                                                             image:thumbnail image
                                                                                               url:urlString
                                                                                       description:description];
```

For general Graph API check this link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects?locale=ko_KR#objectapi-creatingapp